# filter of related selects in ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two (three) `select` tags that list the same options (brans). I would like to prevent user of choosing the same values in these selects.

controller:

```
$scope.brands = [
  {id: '1', name: 'Peugeot'},
  {id: '2', name:'BMW'},
  {id: '3', name:'Mercedes'}
];
```

In template I tried to use `filter` filter in two ways:

```
<body ng-controller="FilterCtrl">
<div>
  <select ng-model="conf.brand1" ng-options="b.id as b.name for b in brands"></select>
</div>

<div>
  <select ng-model="conf.brand2"
          ng-options="b.id as b.name for b in brands | filter : !conf.brand1 : true"></select>
</div>

<div>
  <select ng-model="conf.brand2"
          ng-options="b.id as b.name for b in brands | filter : conf.brand1 : compareBrands"></select>
</div>
</body>
```

with `compareBrands` function:

```
$scope.compareBrands = function(id, already_selected) {
  return id != already_selected;
}
```

none of this is working. Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ta5OViS6fWxjQEy3Zleq?p=preview) of my problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible way is to use `compareBrands` function as expression, to do so, change your third filter to:

```
<select ng-model="conf.brand2" 
          ng-options="b.id as b.name for b in brands | filter : compareBrands"></select>
```

And `compareBrand` function to:

```
$scope.compareBrands = function(obj) {
  return obj.id !== $scope.conf.brand1;
}
```

See [modified plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/E7GK1puouHH5sXRnZY9c?p=preview).

EDIT: I would like to point out that value of `conf.brand1` will be it's id so if you still ok with that and don't want create comparator function for each `select` you should use this form instead:

```
      <select ng-model="conf.brand2" 
          ng-options="b.id as b.name for b in brands | filter : {id: (conf.brand1 ? ('!' + conf.brand1) : '')}"></select>
```